# Check Groupmembership or jobtitle of Logged On User withouth calling azuread (Get-AzureADUserMembership)

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am building a script with a colleague. This script will show a popup.
We want this popup only to be shown to a certain group of users (teachers and not students). So we want to check group membership of a user. Since this script will be installed on the computer locally and we would not like to install azuread cmdlets on all our computers and also not pass azure ad credentials to the script.

So we where wondering if their is azure-ad info about group membership stored on the computers locally. And also if we can acces it via powershell? (if we could get jobtitle of user that would also be helpfull)

Other ideas are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information related user that you are looking for less likely to be stored locally.

So to meet your requirement, you will have to have some means to communicate with the Azure AD. Your requirement was not to make use of any additional libraries and by using  PowerShell.

Graph API can come handy.

To prevent user intervention, you can use **App only** Graph permission for the App.

You can refer to this article to know more App registration, client secret & application permission :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/notifications-integration-app-registration

[image]

You consume the graph endpoint from PowerShell and acquire the necessary details of the logged user from the Azure AD without a necessity of external libraries.

```
# Acquiring the graph token
$web="https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token"
$body = "client_id=<CLIENT ID>&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&client_secret=<CLIENTSECRET>&grant_type=client_credentials"
$response = Invoke-WebRequest $web -Body $body -Method Post
$token = ($response | ConvertFrom-Json).access_token

# Getting the logged username that will be used in the Graph API
$upn = $env:USERNAME + "@" + $env:USERDNSDOMAIN

# building the authorization header
$header = @{"Authorization" = " Bearer $token"}

# getting the user details
$content = Invoke-WebRequest "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$upn" -Headers $header -Method Get
$details = $content.Content | ConvertFrom-Json

# getting the group membership
$content =  Invoke-WebRequest "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$upn/memberof" -Headers $header -Method Get
$groupdetails = ($content.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).value
```